# Is there any option available to make setDomStorageEnabled to true in webview_flutter plugin?

Tags: flutter, dom, webview, local-storage, webview-flutter

I am trying to add webview inside my flutter application and for that i need to allow dom storage to access data stored. Currently i guess web_view flutter plugin not allows any way to setDomainStorageEnabled to true. But is there someone have any information of got any workaround fix for that?

It is working fine with native android as WebSetting allows me to make domstorageenable to true.

But in flutter webview_flutter plugin that dosen't seems possible.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @Sohag No not so far